# How to get PhpStorm to recognise a function only used in a separate ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript, phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

I'm working on some production code and there is a `.js` file with a function defined in it that is used only in a `.ts` file. The `.ts` file has a working `/// <reference path="..."/>` to the `.js` file, and when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click on the function call in the `.ts` file, it takes me straight to the function definition in the `.js` file.

However, in the `.js` file, the function is reported as `Unused function ...`. I'd like to be able to both fix the warning (without disabling it), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click on the function definition to find all of its uses. Currently when I do that, it says `No usages found in Project Files`.

PhpStorm has obviously linked from the `.ts` file to the `.js` file, but how to I get it to recognise that the `.js` file is also linked to the `.ts` file?

Comment: What is the intended result of ctrl+click in php storm?

Comment: @RyanAmundson As described. Show the definition for the clicked usage or show usages for the clicked definition. This works across files 99% of the time.

Comment: Some code would be helpful as well but I suspect the definition or usages are not Typed properly. The way it finds usages is based on having the TypeScript types set up correctly.

Comment: @RyanAmundson JavaScript is not typed but can be called directly from TypeScript anyway.

Comment: To clear your warnings of unused function you need to remove the js files or folders from going through the TS transpiling process. This is done in the tsconfig. In modern optimized apps typescript files are transpiled (and packed , minified,etc) to a seperate folder which is what is served to the browser. js map files can then be used for debugging. maybe that what you want a .js.map file.

Comment: @RyanAmundson .js files don't go through the transpilation process. .ts files get transpiled to .js files.

Comment: I understand that... I am telling you since TS is a superset of JS it will read both files TS and JS. Your issue may be stemming from an already transpiled JS file going through the process again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154396/discussion-between-cj-dennis-and-ryan-amundson).

Comment: Importing JavaScript modules in typescript is not currently supported;
this feature (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21443) will be available in 2017.3